# ggmap geocode works locally but not on Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, ggmap, geocode

I have a simple [app](https://carlosgg.shinyapps.io/ggmap-test/) that works on my computer but not when I deploy.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggmap)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h3("Test ggmap")),
  sidebarLayout (
    sidebarPanel(
           textInput("address", label=h4("Enter location"), value = 
"Millenia Mall, Orlando")
    ),
    mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("debug"))
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny) 
library(ggmap) 
register_google(key = "abc123")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$debug <- renderPrint({
        location <- as.numeric(geocode(input$address, source="google"))
        location
    })
})
```

On my computer I get:

```
[1] -81.43153  28.48553
```

On the server:

```
[1] NA NA
```

On the Shiny server log, it says:

```
Warning in readLines(connect, warn = FALSE) : unsupported URL scheme
Warning in geocode(input$address, source = "google") :
    geocoding failed for "Millenia Mall, Orlando".
```

I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153255/geocode-from-ggmap-fails-on-shiny-server), with the `global.R` file, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you use the same API key for both? Try `geocode(..., output = "all")` and see what it says.

Comment: Can you try setting the following option in your server.R?  `options(download.file.method = "wget")`

Comment: Roman, yes, same API key. When I use `output = all`, I get a long output on this computer but on the Shiny server it just says NA.

Comment: tcash21, I tried that line on server.R but the result is the same.